# How to get around undefined method `send_keys'

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, rack

I'm getting `undefined method 'send_keys'` when running feature tests in our Ruby on Rails application we've been using over the past 3 years when trying to run our rspec-capybara tests

We have the `gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.47.1'` in our `Gemfile` and it shows in Gemfile.lock

we suspect we're not using the right driver but given our `Gemfile`, not sure why not

HTML we're targeting:

```
<input class="zip-code-input" id="landing-zip-code" maxlength="5" name="landing[zip_code]"
pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="ZIP Code" size="5" tabindex="1" title="Five-Digit ZIP Code"  
value="" type="text">
```

I see a lot of references to rack in the Gemfile.lock, i.e.

```
$ bundle | grep rack
Using rack 1.4.7
Using crack 0.3.2
Using rack-cache 1.5.1
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using rack-ssl 1.3.4
Using rack-protection 1.5.3
Using rack_session_access 0.1.1
```

but I've been unable to find any way to change that

send_keys is documented here:
https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#send_keys-instance_method

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Isn't the method called sendKeys? - edit ok it's not

Comment: What object are you trying to send keys too? You are saying the selenium code was all working before?

Comment: Added the send_keys method (btw not the same as the .net method)

Comment: We're trying to enter a zip code in asn input field with `.set` but it isn't working so we're trying send_keys

Comment: @MichaelDurrant What is the full error? And can you post a code snippet of the selenium code as well as the html

Comment: When this kind of issue occurs for me, it's usually because the object on which it's calling the method is not of the class I expect, and is usually nil. Is it possible that the thing fetching the element is returning nil?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using capybara gem and if you are trying to fill the text field, then you have to use the below syntax.

fill_in 'landing-zip-code', with: '123456'

Find the reference [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FActions%3Afill_in)